# How to install Pythonika on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, python

I tried to install [Pythonika](https://code.google.com/p/pythonika/) on my Ubuntu 14.04 (64) with python 2.7.6. I followed Salem's answer, but there are some errors.

The `Makefile.linux`

```
# Set the paths according to your MathLink Developer Kit location.
# (The paths should not contain whitespaces)

MATHEMATICA_INSTALL_DIR = /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.0
MLINKDIR = ${MATHEMATICA_INSTALL_DIR}/SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit

SYS = Linux-x86-64
CADDSDIR = ${MLINKDIR}/${SYS}/CompilerAdditions

INCDIR = ${CADDSDIR}
LIBDIR = ${CADDSDIR}

MPREP = "${CADDSDIR}/mprep"
MCC = "${CADDSDIR}/mcc"

# Modify the following for Python versions other than 2.6
PYTHON_VERSION_MAJOR = 2
PYTHON_VERSION_MINOR = 7


# Path to the Python includes (modify according to Python version)
#
PYTHONINC = /usr/include/python${PYTHON_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PYTHON_VERSION_MINOR}/


PYTHONIKA = Pythonika
INCLUDES = -I${INCDIR} -I${PYTHONINC}

# libstdc++ and librt are, apparently, needed for correct compilation under Linux
# with libMLi3 statically linked
#
##     Ununtu 14.04 
LIBS = -L${LIBDIR} ${LIBDIR}/libML64i3.a -lstdc++ -lpthread -lm -lrt -    lpython${PYTHON_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PYTHON_VERSION_MINOR}


all : Pythonika

Pythonika: ${PYTHONIKA}.o ${PYTHONIKA}tm.o
${CC} ${INCLUDES} ${PYTHONIKA}.o ${PYTHONIKA}tm.o ${LIBS} -o ${PYTHONIKA}

${PYTHONIKA}tm.o: ${PYTHONIKA}.tm
${MPREP} ${PYTHONIKA}.tm -o ${PYTHONIKA}tm.c
${CC} -c ${PYTHONIKA}tm.c ${INCLUDES}

${PYTHONIKA}.o: ${PYTHONIKA}.c
${CC} -c ${PYTHONIKA}.c ${INCLUDES}

clean :
rm -f ${PYTHONIKA}tm.* ${PYTHONIKA}.o ${PYTHONIKA}
```

The error is

```
cc -I/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.0/SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/Linux-x86-64/CompilerAdditions -I/usr/include/python2.7/ Pythonika.o Pythonikatm.o -L/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.0/SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/Linux-x86-64/CompilerAdditions        /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.0/SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/Linux-x86-64/CompilerAdditions/libML64i3.a -lstdc++ -lpthread -lm -lrt -lpython2.7 -o Pythonika
Pythonikatm.o: In function `MLAnswer':
Pythonikatm.c:(.text+0xba8): undefined reference to `MLWaitForLinkActivity'
/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.0/SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/Linux-x86-64/CompilerAdditions/libML64i3.a(mluuid.cpp.o): In function `MathLink::MLUUID::stringRepresentation() const':
mluuid.cpp:(.text+0x7e): undefined reference to `uuid_unparse_upper'
/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.0/SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/Linux-x86-64/CompilerAdditions/libML64i3.a(mluuid.cpp.o): In function `MathLink::MLUUID::operator=(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, MathLink::MLStdAllocator<char> > const&)':
mluuid.cpp:(.text+0xd4): undefined reference to `uuid_parse'
/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.0/SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/Linux-x86-64/CompilerAdditions/libML64i3.a(mluuid.cpp.o): In function `MathLink::MLUUID::MLUUID(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, MathLink::MLStdAllocator<char> > const&)':
mluuid.cpp:(.text+0x17b): undefined reference to `uuid_parse'
/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.0/SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/Linux-x86-64/CompilerAdditions/libML64i3.a(mluuid.cpp.o): In function `MathLink::MLUUID::MLUUID()':
mluuid.cpp:(.text+0x227): undefined reference to `uuid_generate'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Pythonika] Error 1
```

Comment: What error(s) did you get while installing?

Comment: @M.Tarun I even cannot find the file to install, so no error. Thanks!

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/pythonika/downloads/list

Comment: @M.Tarun Thanks! I download the first file but cannot open it. And the rest files may be not for Ubuntu.

Comment: @EdenHarder    Have you solved your problem?

Comment: @Salem No, can you help me?

Comment: Using the instructions I gave below what happens? You get any error?

Answer (score 1):

None of the compiled versions available match your OS/arch, so you will need to compile it by yourself. Roughly, you need to follow those steps:

- Install the building tools

  ```
  $ sudo apt-get install build-essential subversion python-dev
  ```
- Get the source code:

  ```
  $ svn checkout http://pythonika.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ pythonika-src
  $ cd pythonika-src
  ```
- Edit the file `Makefile.linux` and check the path in `MATHEMATICA_INSTALL_DIR` is correct. Also you will need to change `PYTHON_VERSION_MINOR` to "7" (if you are using the python version installed by default).
- Compile it

  ```
  $ make -f Makefile.linux
  ```

If everything went well, you should have a file named `Pythonika` inside that folder.
If you get any error, update your question with the errors you get.

Comment: [Mat](http://askubuntu.com/users/212205/mat) says: "I get following error on Ubuntu 12:
`sudo make -f Makefile.linux`  `cc -c Pythonika.c -I/usr/local/Wolfram/M[...]
/bin/sh: 1: /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/Linux/CompilerAdditions/mprep: not found
make: *** [Pythonikatm.o] Error 127`

Comment: @MadMike Well it seems you don't have Mathematica or MathLink installed, or it is installed somewhere else. See if this helps: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/MathLinkDeveloperGuide-Unix.html#26966

Answer (score 0):

You have to install `uuid-dev` package. You can do so by executing this command in Terminal (to launch Terminal do <kbd>CRTL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>):

```
sudo apt-get install uuid-dev
```

And say in `Makefile.linux` file that you need the library `libuuid.so`. To do that, edit the file and add `-luuid` to the line:

> LIBS = -L${LIBDIR} ${LIBDIR}/libML64i3.a -lstdc++ -lpthread -lm -lrt
>   -lpython${PYTHON_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PYTHON_VERSION_MINOR}

So you should have something like this:

> LIBS = -L${LIBDIR} ${LIBDIR}/libML64i3.a -lstdc++ -luuid -lpthread -lm
>   -lrt -lpython${PYTHON_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PYTHON_VERSION_MINOR}

That's all.